ошибка при запуске приложения и при запуске с флагом debug
При запуске в эмуляторе андроид - приложение просто закрывется, нет никакого текста ошибки.


Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 2.
java.io.IOException: ���� �������� ������
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.forwardContent(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.streams.ExecOutputHandleRunner.run(ExecOutputHandleRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)



При этом , нажимаю Структура проекта, в вкладке modules, подвкладке Properties: compile sdk стоит версия  34, java -  1.8. И тоже на вкладке default config.
андроид плагин - 8.2.2
градл версион - 8.2
менял версию джава с 1.8 на 1.7 - те же ошибки


  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }



Подскажите, в чем проблема?

См. Broken pipe error when running Gradle test, How to fix 'Could not write standard input to Gradle Test Executor 1' error in Java


я убирал опцию -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 из файла gradle.properties. Не помогло.
файла build.gradle у меня нет, только build.gradle.kt в котором нет путей. Пусть есть в local.properties и указан путь к sdkdir = c:\AndroidStudio




файла build.gradle у меня нет, только build.gradle.kt в котором нет путей. Пусть есть в local.properties и указан путь к sdkdir = c:\AndroidStudio
в build.gradle.kts указано 1.8 и в дефолтКонфиг и в КомпилеОпшн также стоит 1.8 версия Джавы.
Ни один совет не помог из вышеуказанной статьи

